# Position of Status Bar in my device

Tags: android

I want to know how can I get position of status bar? On my included screenshot status bar is on bottom of screen, together with navigation bar. How can I check it programmatically? In activity or fragment.

Question: how can I know when status bar is on TOP of screen or at BOTTOM of screen?

http://snag.gy/j8gST.jpg

// Anyone who knows how can I resolve my problem?

Comment: there is nothing that tells you where the status bar is

Comment: So how can I distinguish between top or bot position of status bar? No chance to know it?

Comment: no why would you even need to know that

Comment: I drawing list of 6 categories on my screen. Height of one category equal 1/6 of my screen. But when I want to draw it on device with bottom status bar, my last category is too small and left white space. Any idea to fix it?

+ white space equal size of status bar, in my case 19px

Answer (score 1):

Ypu could just try to Hide that bar using the following line of code !

```
<application
...
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
...
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"
```